# starting audio with javascript on android after a countdown

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio

I'd like to start an audio clip at a specific time with javascript in the browser of android. The following code with HTML5 works fine on my laptop, the countdown works on android, too, and I can manually start the clip (4.1 jelly bean). So the codec is supported, the javascript itself should be okay for firefox and chrome on a laptop (linux), but something's wrong on android: **the audio.play() does not start the audio. But if I make a button that calls audio.play() it works.**

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>countdown and play</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
deadline = new Date(2012,7,16,1,8,00);


function countdown() 
{
    var now = new Date();
    if (deadline-now <= 0){
        var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
        audio.play();
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML="time's up!";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML=Math.ceil((deadline-now)/60000)+" minute(s) to go!";
        t=setTimeout(function(){countdown()},500);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="countdown">starting countdown</p>
<audio src="audio.ogg" preload="auto" controls>
<p>Your browser does not support the audio element </p>
</audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
audio.load();
audio.onloadeddata = countdown();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

any ideas?
thanks in advance

Comment: **something's wrong on android**. What exactly is wrong?

Comment: the audio.play() does not start the audio. But if I make a button that calls audio.play() it works.

Comment: Does the `countdown()`-function get triggered?

Comment: yes, the countdown works, i.e. it get's triggered and the minutes are displayed correctly, also the "time's up" when the deadline is reached.